# Rollup trigger not working

Tags: apex, trigger

Can anyone determine the error int he code below?  The 
The SampleOrderCount__c file dis not getting populated.

```
trigger SumScoringValuesfromActivities on Task (after insert, after update)

{
    set<string> S1IdSet = new set<string>();
    list<Lead> updateS1List = new list<Lead>();

    for(task tsk : trigger.new)
    {
        if(tsk.whatid != null && tsk.whatid.getsObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType)
        {
            S1IdSet.add(tsk.WhatId);
        }
    }


    for(Lead s1: [select id,SampleOrderCount__c, (select id,whatid,Lead_Activity_Scoring__c  from Tasks) from Lead where id in :S1IdSet])
    {
        s1.SampleOrderCount__c = 0;
        for(task tk : s1.Tasks)
        {
            if(tk.Lead_Activity_Scoring__c  != null)
            {
                s1.SampleOrderCount__c += tk.Lead_Activity_Scoring__c ;

            }
        }
       updateS1List.add(s1);
    }
    update updateS1List;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried putting system.debug and check values of the S1IdSet?

Comment: Coming at it logically, `S1IdSet` could be empty, causing your outer soql for loop to have no results to iterate over. If that set isn't empty, then `s1.Tasks` should always have at least 1 record in it, but `Lead_Activity_Scoring__c` could be null (meaning you never actually increment your count). Including strategically placed debug statements and digging through the debug logs should tell you what's going on.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, consider using **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  There is an Activity on the Lead record and the Lead_Activity_Scoring__c field does have a value.   Now there is a workflow that populated the Lead_Activity_Scoring__c field when the Activity is created.  But even if I manually go into the Activity and resave it it does not update the SampleOrderCount field on the Lead record.  Let me try to insert some debugging statements in teh trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll reiterate what I said in the comments. You don't need to write any code for this requirement, as there are plenty of well built (and free) tools out there to do what you need. Specifically, **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** is well known, well built, and easy to configure.

Of the benefits:

- Your logic would not have gaps like missing database events (`delete`, `undelete`).
- You can backfill data using pre-built batches.
- The tool is well built and fully tested.

You would just need to create one `Lookup Rollup Summary` record here:

```
Summary Field             Value
==================================================
Parent Object             Lead
Relationship Field        WhatId
Child Object              Task
Field to Aggregate        Lead_Activity_Scoring__c
Aggregate Operation       Sum
Aggregate Result Field    SampleOrderCount__c
```

Comment: Adrian, thank you for the information. I have installed the package and configuring it for relatime but no update on the Lead object.  I have deployed the Apex code as instructed.  I will keep trying.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure it is active? And remove the trigger logic you wrote above?

Comment: The Rollup is Active and the my Apex Trigger is inactive.  The 2 fields that are are being referenced are of the type number. Is there any other configuration changes needed on the Summary itself?

Comment: The Aggregate field is showing 0 even though the re are numeric values in the Lead_Activity_Scoring__c field. I have removed the Installed package and reinstalled but no change.  Any thoughts?

Comment: OK.  Relationship Field needs to be set to 'WhoId'.  Is there a way to do a mass update to existing Lead records?

Comment: Yeah just run the calculate job. There's a button for it on the summary layout.

Comment: Ok, By the help topic  I assumed you had to reference a specific record or group of records.  Also, there is a 'relationship criteria' filed on the user interface.  Can I use a clause like 'Lead_Activity_Scoring__c > 0' so that the process only looks for child records that have value for the Lead_Activity_Scoring__c filed?  Is there anywhere to limit the Parent records?  For example where Lead Type =  'Consumer.  Not sure if that would make the process more efficient.